# Reverse line order except header

Tags: shell, unix, awk, posix

With a shell command I want to reverse the lines of a text file, excluding the header line.

```
Number,Letter,Person
1,a,Alice
2,b,Bob
3,c,Claire
```

should become

```
Number,Letter,Person
3,c,Claire
2,b,Bob
1,a,Alice
```

I'm looking for *both* an "in place" solution (change original file) and a streaming solution (read original file from stdin and print result to stdout).

Ideally, the command or script would be POSIX compatible, but other solutions could also be interesting. A oneliner would be nice.

I'm also interested in the performance/complexity of any solution.

Comment: @anubhava Why did you change the tags? Awk is fine, but certainly not required.

Comment: oh sorry, I thought `awk` being a popular tag will give more visibility to your question. Feel free to revert back if you don't like.

Comment: @anubhava No problem. I was just curious.

Comment: interesting question and requirements, but you need to show [your own code/research attempts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) too :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an `awk` command to do this:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END{print a[1]; for (i=NR; i>1; i--) print a[i]}' file

Number,Letter,Person
3,c,Claire
2,b,Bob
1,a,Alice
```

Here `a[1]` represents header record. Remaining entries in associative array `a` represent rows with the index as record number.

Alternatively, using `head, tail, cat`:

```
{ head -1 f && tail -n +2 file | tac; } > file._tmp && mv file._tmp file

Number,Letter,Person
3,c,Claire
2,b,Bob
1,a,Alice
```

Comment: How come the second command is in a code block? Also is `<()` POSIX, why not just use a pipe?

Comment: Could you explain how to use your solutions as a pipe and inline?

Comment: I have changed my answer to pipeline now.

Comment: How about inline? (chaging the original file, instead of piping)

Comment: `head, tail, cat` cannot change a file inline so I added an option to save output in a temp file and overwrite original file. However if you have access to `gnu awk` then we can use inline option.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '1p;2h;3,${G;h};$p' file
```

Output:

```
Number,Letter,Person
3,c,Claire
2,b,Bob
1,a,Alice
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

---

See: `man sed`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR==1), NR, $0}' file | sort -snr -k1 -k2 | cut -f3-
Number,Letter,Person
3,c,Claire
2,b,Bob
1,a,Alice
```